# How to check what column in INSERT do not have the correct data type?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, mybatis

Imagine I have 200 columns in one `INSERT` statement, and I occasionally get an "Cannot convert" error for one of columns. Things is, I do not know which column causes this error.

Is there any way in T-SQL or mybatis to check WHICH column has the incorrect format? (I have just date, char, numeric). I can use `ISNUMERIC`, `ISDATE` for every column, but this is not so elegant.

I'm using mybatis in Java, so I cannot use any `PreparedStatement` or so.

Comment: Use parameters & binding so you won't get that error since your variables should be the correct type. Also, `isnumeric` doesn't even guarantee you won't get the error.

Comment: I'm using mybatis in Java.

Comment: [`IsNumeric()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/isnumeric-transact-sql) is notoriously [problematic](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/ISNUMERIC()/71512/). Modern versions of SQL Server have [`Try_Convert()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/try-convert-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017).

Answer (score 1):

You could build a query that tries to convert each of the suspected columns.
And limit the query to where one of the attempts to convert fails.

Mostly the bad data will be in CHAR's or VARCHAR's when trying to cast or convert them to a datetime or number type.
So you can limit your research to those.
Also, from the error you should see which value failed to convert to which type.  Which can also help to limit which fields you research.

A simplified example using table variables:

```
declare @T1 table (id int identity(1,1) primary key, field1 varchar(30), field2 varchar(30), field3 varchar(30));
declare @T2 table (id int identity(1,1) primary key, field1_int int, field2_date date, field3_dec decimal(10,2));

insert into @T1 (field1, field2, field3) values
('1','2018-01-01','1.23'),
('not an int','2018-01-01','1.23'),
('1','not a date','1.23'),
('1','2018-01-01','not a decimal'),
(null,'2018-01-01','1.23'),
('1',null,'1.23'),
('1','2018-01-01',null)
;

select top 1000
id,
case when try_convert(int, field1) is null then field1 end as field1,
case when try_convert(date, field2) is null then field2 end as field2,
case when try_convert(decimal(10,4), field3) is null then field3 end as field3
from @T1
where 
   try_convert(int, coalesce(field1, '0')) is null
or try_convert(date, coalesce(field2, '1900-01-01')) is null
or try_convert(decimal(10,4), coalesce(field3, '0.0')) is null;
```

Returns:

```
id  field1      field2       field3
--  ----------  -----------  -------------
2   not an int  NULL         NULL
3   NULL        not a date   NULL
4   NULL        NULL         not a decimal
```

If the origin data doesn't have to much bad data you could try to fix the origin data first.

Or use the try_convert for the problematic columns with bad data.

For example:

```
insert into @T2 (field1_int, field2_date, field3_dec)
select 
try_convert(int, field1),
try_convert(date, field2),
try_convert(decimal(10,4), field3)
from @T1;
```

Comment: Thumbs up from my side. I borrowed part of your answer to provide a fully generic approach.

Answer (score 1):

With larger imports - especially when you expect issues - a two-stepped approach is highly recommended.

1. import the data to a very tolerant staging table (all `NVARCHAR(MAX)`)
2. check, evaluate, manipulate, correct whatever is needed and do the real insert from here

Here is a generic approach you might adapt to your needs. It will check all tables values against a type-map-table and output all values, which fail in `TRY_CAST` (needs SQL-Server 2012+)

A table to *mockup* the staging table (partly borrowed from LukStorms' answer - thx!)

```
CREATE TABLE #T1 (id INT IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY
                 ,fldInt VARCHAR(30)
                 ,fldDate VARCHAR(30)
                 ,fldDecimal VARCHAR(30));
GO

INSERT INTO #T1 (fldInt, fldDate, fldDecimal) values
('1','2018-01-01','1.23'),
('blah','2018-01-01','1.23'),
('1','blah','1.23'),
('1','2018-01-01','blah'),
(null,'2018-01-01','1.23'),
('1',null,'1.23'),
('1','2018-01-01',null);
```

--a type map (might be taken from `INFORMATION_SCHEMA` of an existing target table automatically)

```
DECLARE @type_map TABLE(ColumnName VARCHAR(100),ColumnType VARCHAR(100));
INSERT INTO @type_map VALUES('fldInt','int')
                           ,('fldDate','date')
                           ,('fldDecimal','decimal(10,2)');
```

--The staging table's name

```
DECLARE @TableName NVARCHAR(100)='#T1';
```

--dynamically created statements for each column

```
DECLARE @columnSelect NVARCHAR(MAX)=
(SELECT
    ' UNION ALL SELECT id ,''' +  tm.ColumnName + ''',''' +  tm.ColumnType + ''',' +  QUOTENAME(tm.ColumnName) 
               + ',CASE WHEN TRY_CAST(' + QUOTENAME(tm.ColumnName) + ' AS ' +  tm.ColumnType + ') IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END ' +
               'FROM ' + QUOTENAME(@TableName)
 FROM @type_map AS tm
 FOR XML PATH('')
);
```

-The final dynamically created statement

```
DECLARE @cmd NVARCHAR(MAX)=
'SELECT tbl.*
FROM
(
    SELECT 0 AS id,'''' AS ColumnName,'''' AS ColumnType,'''' AS ColumnValue,0 AS IsValid WHERE 1=0 '
  + @columnSelect +
') AS tbl
WHERE tbl.IsValid = 0;'
```

--Execution with `EXEC()`

```
EXEC(@cmd);
```

The result:

```
+----+------------+---------------+-------------+---------+
| id | ColumnName | ColumnType    | ColumnValue | IsValid |
+----+------------+---------------+-------------+---------+
| 2  | fldInt     | int           | blah        | 0       |
+----+------------+---------------+-------------+---------+
| 5  | fldInt     | int           | NULL        | 0       |
+----+------------+---------------+-------------+---------+
| 3  | fldDate    | date          | blah        | 0       |
+----+------------+---------------+-------------+---------+
| 6  | fldDate    | date          | NULL        | 0       |
+----+------------+---------------+-------------+---------+
| 4  | fldDecimal | decimal(10,2) | blah        | 0       |
+----+------------+---------------+-------------+---------+
| 7  | fldDecimal | decimal(10,2) | NULL        | 0       |
+----+------------+---------------+-------------+---------+
```

The statement created is like here:

```
SELECT tbl.*
FROM
(
    SELECT 0 AS id,'' AS ColumnName,'' AS ColumnType,'' AS ColumnValue,0 AS IsValid WHERE 1=0 
    UNION ALL SELECT id 
                    ,'fldInt'
                    ,'int'
                    ,[fldInt]
                    ,CASE WHEN TRY_CAST([fldInt] AS int) IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END 
              FROM [#T1]
    UNION ALL SELECT id 
                    ,'fldDate'
                    ,'date',[fldDate]
                    ,CASE WHEN TRY_CAST([fldDate] AS date) IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END 
              FROM [#T1]
    UNION ALL SELECT id 
                   ,'fldDecimal'
                   ,'decimal(10,2)'
                   ,[fldDecimal]
                   ,CASE WHEN TRY_CAST([fldDecimal] AS decimal(10,2)) IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END 
              FROM [#T1]
) AS tbl
WHERE tbl.IsValid = 0;
```

Comment: You got my upvote :)  I do like this approach. Not 100% generic because you still need to  fill the type_map. But it does save a lot of time. Just personally, I probably wouldn't give that "tolerant staging table" all nvarchars. Because with most implicit conversions from datetime and numeric, one can expect them to work.

Comment: @LukStorms Thx! :-D  - About *not 100% generic*: I've written there, that the information of `@type_map` might be taken from an existing target table  automatically. And about *all `NVARCHAR(MAX)`: Using one simple schema *for everything* allows for a generic approach. If one has to deal with failing imports more often, such an approach can be packed as SP and run against *each and any* import...